# How to fix appendix section headings while using titlesec package?

Tags: titlesec, article, appendix

I am writing a paper using `article` class. I use the `titlesec` package with `[sc]` option, e.g. `\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}` to write the document headings in small caps. When I use this package, it wrecks the headings in the appendix like this:[image]
It does not mess with section headings of main body though. What is causing this and how to fix it? Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}
\title{The Earth Shattering Paper}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\appendix
\begin{center}
\section*{\textsc{ONLINE APPENDIX}\\[0.8cm]
The Earth Shattering Paper\\[0.8cm]
Dr Smarty Pants}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of \begin{center} is wrong. It makes the lines filled. Put it in the section title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}
\title{The Earth Shattering Paper}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\appendix
%\centering%\begin{center}
\section*{\centering{\textsc
{ONLINE APPENDIX}}\\[0.8cm]
The Earth Shattering Paper\\[0.8cm]
Dr Smarty Pants}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Appendix title centered]

Comment: Thanks, @c-peters. It worked. Can I ask why the position of \begin{center} was wrong in my code? I mean, when I usually use the command \begin {center}, it centers the text in the middle of the row but in this specific case, it was filling the line with the text.

Comment: With the brackets of the section title you make a box which is centered as such. You could have used \begin{center} and \end{center} within the brackets of your section title as well (but why use two codes if one is sufficient). In both cases you center the content of the box. In some cases \centering and \begin{center} lead to different results. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it.